# UISearchDisplayController within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am developing an iOS application in C# using Xamarin Studio and I have a `UITableViewController` consisting of multiple `UITableViewCells`. In one of those cells I need to have a `UISearchBar` with its `UISearchDisplayController`. My problem is that I can not manage to have the `UISearchDisplayController` and show the search results within this `UITableViewCell`. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am aware of the fact that `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: you try to add one? please share the code how you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Add delegate in header file,

Add these two methods in your tableview

[Add these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oh6T.png)

Comment: also add delegate for search like 'Add delegate in header file, 

<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>' @Stefan Stefanov

Comment: I am sorry but I forgot to mention that I am implementing the app in C# using Xamarin Studio.